# Is there an equivalent to CCMoveTo in Carona SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, coronasdk

In Cocos2d you can move a sprite to a specific position using the "CCMoveTo" method like so:

```
[sprite runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]]; //Moves a sprite to the position "location" in 1 second.
```

Is there something like this in the Corona SDK? I've tried some Googling but nothing is coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a similar method to CCMoveTo:

[transition.to](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/transitionto)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at the following API Example:

[`spriteInstance:play()`](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/spriteinstanceplay)

Where you can set different properties of that particular sprite and play to the new animation. It doesn't say anything about the duration though.

Comment: Where would I specify the new location in this function?

Comment: `instance2.x = display.contentWidth / 2` is changing the `x` coordinate of that given sprite. I think you could do something similar.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a function of similar results (preferably dead on same) as the `CCMoveTo`, and I would rather not have to write it myself. I could do hand manipulation of `.x` and `.y` but I am looking for an alternative. If there is none then I will go about writing it.